# LINQ + short circuit based on array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I've got a simple LINQ query that I'd like to short circuit, based on the first matching value in the array.I just want to return, based on the first value in the xmlDoc that matches the first item in the array, eg if it matches "B", then it will exit, if it doesn't then it'll try to match against "C" etc.

I could of course have looped through the array manually and verified whether the value was NULL, and this may be what I have to do, but I've been looking to see if there's a more elegant way to do this.

Many thanks,

yogi

```
string[] searchTypes = { "B", "C", "D", "A" };
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

for (int i = 0; i < searchTypes.Length; i++)
    commsValue = (from r in xDoc.Descendants("Root")
                  where r.Element("dCode") != null &&    r.Element("dCode").Value == searchTypes[i])
select r.Element("Number").Value).FirstOrDefault();
if (commsValue == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
```

}

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you'd provide a short but *complete* example, with sample input and expected output. I don't follow what you're trying to do at the moment.

Comment: If by "elegant" you mean a Linq query that is obvious to whomever reads it what it is doing, then no, there's not an "elegant" solution.  Stick with a loop that you can understand and be able to explain.

Comment: Something like `searchTypes.Contains(r.Element("dCode").Value.ToString())`?

Comment: @ArthurRey That would short-circuit the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks guys, for all the replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can make your loop a single loop of `xDoc.Descendants("Root")` (which linq loops internally) and reduce the lookup of the array.

First create a lookup dictionary from `searchTypes`:

```
var lookup = new [] { "B", "C", "D", "A" }
  .Select((e, i) => new {Key = e, Index = i})
  .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Index);
```

Now for `"B"` you have `0`, for `"C"` you have `1` and so on.

Now for the actual loop:

```
int curIndex = int.MaxValue;
foreach(var r in xDoc.Descendants("Root"))
{
  int index;
  if (r.Element("dCode") != null && lookup.TryGetValue(r.Element("dCode").Value, out index))
  {
    if (index == 0)
    {
      commsValue = r.Element("Number").Value;
      break; // short-circuit
    }
    else if (index < curIndex)
    {
      commsValue = r.Element("Number").Value; // Value to have after finished loop.
      curIndex = index;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way of doing a short-circuit that I am aware of.  The way you have worded your question, it will search the entire XML nodelist for "B" and if it isn't found, then search the entire nodelist for "C", etc.

It is hard to get a good answer for you without a lot more details.  How often is "B" expected to be found, and how many nodes does the XML doc have?  You could traverse the entire nodelist, keeping track of the best match as you go, exitting when you find the first "B", or at the end, then return the best non-B result.  But no such built-in LINQ method exists, but you could build your own custom one that did.

```
public static XmlNode FindBestNode(this IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes, string[] vals)
{
   XmlNode best=null;
   int bestindex=vals.length+1;
   while(nodes.MoveNext())
   {
     var currindex=vals.indexOf(nodes.Current.Element("dCode").Value));
     if (currindex>=0) {
       if (currindex==0) return nodes.Current;
       if (currindex<bestindex) {
         bestindex=currindex;
         best=nodes.Current;
     }
   }
   return best;
}
```

I'm not an expert at xml queries, but the above should be pretty close.

Used like:

```
string[] searchTypes = { "B", "C", "D", "A" };
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var bestNode=xDoc.Descendants("Root")
  .Where(r=>r.Element("dCode")!=null)
  .FindBestNode(searchTypes);
```

Comment: ok, I updated the code to show how I'd do it in forLoop. Thanks

Comment: This is pretty much the same answer as Jon's below, but returns the actual Node instead of the value, it doesn't use a dictionary, and wrapped into an extension method.  His is actually better, so I'll upvote his answer.  I'll keep this one here just for an example, but you should use his answer.  I believe his use of the dictionary in most cases will scale better than an `Array.indexOf`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that in a join the sort order of the first collection is preserved. So join `serachTypes` with `xDoc.Descendants("Root")` and take the first element:

```
string[] searchTypes = { "B", "C", "D", "A" };
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

var commsValue = (from st in searchTypes
                  join r in xDoc.Descendants("Root")
                      on st equals r.Element("dCode").Value
                  where r.Element("dCode") != null)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```